Split Cell Value into rows in mutiples of 10
I have a range of data that I need to split and add rows into mutiples of 10. See below eg.
John    32
Paul    21
Needs to become:
John    10
John    10
John    10
John    2
Paul    10
Paul    10
Paul    1
I've fiddled around but I have no idea how to get this right.
Thanks.

Here is one way of doing this in MS365:


• Formula used in cell D2
=LET(
     _Data, B2:B3,
     _Values, --TEXTAFTER(_Data," "),
     _N, SEQUENCE(,ROUNDUP(MAX(_Values)/10,)),
     _Split, IF(_Values>10*_N,10,_Values+10-_N*10),
     TOCOL(IFS(_Split>0,TEXTBEFORE(_Data," ")&" "&_Split),2))



Thanks very much but I was a bit unclear, the text is in a column and the numbers are in  seperate column. So for example John is in column A and 32 in column B and then the split needs to be the same John in coloumn A and 10 in column B.

@ShaneBranscombe there will not be a big difference, use this : =LET(      _Values, C2:C3,      _N, SEQUENCE(,ROUNDUP(MAX(_Values)/10,)),      _Split, IF(_Values>10*_N,10,_Values+10-_N*10),      TOCOL(IFS(_Split>0,B2:B3&" "&_Split),2))

Thank you, its working!

Sorry I've just realised something I need result of the formula to insert as new rows so for example from your screenshot, Row 2,3,4,5 will say John in column B, and Row 2,3,4 Column C will have 10 and Row 5 will have 2. Is this possible?

Maybe a macro will work?

@ShaneBranscombe whatever you have tried please update the original post, to show users that you have tried using this macro or formula etc.

@Shane Branscombe, couldn't you just nest Mayukh Bhattacharya's formula inside TEXTSPLIT()?
